# Valgrind output when all the threads do not terminate

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

It is more of a general query, what would be the behaviour of valgrind memcheck if some of the threads spawned do not gracefully terminate. I mean the case when the threads are detached and do not share any memory with parent process/ thread.

I dont have any code snippet or valgrind output, as it is a question just out of curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this piece of code:

```
while (1) {
    pthread_t thread;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
    int newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);

    if (newsock == -1) {
        perror("accept");
    } else {
        if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handle, &newsock) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
        } else {
            pthread_detach(thread);
        }
    }
    if (count == 5) break;
}
close(sock);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Where a thread is still waiting for `accept()`, it shows a possibly lost:

```
david@debian:~$ valgrind ./server
==24561== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24561== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24561== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24561== Command: ./server
==24561== 
0
1
2
3
4
5
==24561== 
==24561== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24561==     in use at exit: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==24561==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 1,408 bytes allocated
==24561== 
==24561== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24561==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24561==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24561==      possibly lost: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==24561==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24561==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24561== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==24561== 
==24561== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24561== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: If the process doesn't fail on termination, don't worry about it.

Comment: In this case what about the thread created by pthread_create() ? , it would gets some memory of its own ( with in the process of course) and is not de allocated on when the parent is down since it is a detached thread.

Comment: The main thread doesn't wait for his childs and all the opened threads are interrupted, therefore you give a possible memory leak, use a mutex to sinchronize threads

Comment: 'is not de allocated on when the parent is down since it is a detached thread' - sure it is.  Process termination means death of all threads in the process and, afterward, deallocation of all stack etc.  memory.  The OS can, and will, terminate all threads, in any state, running on any core or not, whenever any process thread calls for process termination.  There will be no leak of anything.